# how to decrement count value that is in a nested array within a reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to increment, and decrement on each click(its for a like button). I figured out the logic to increment a like value, but how would i go about decrementing the value ?

The count is pretty much the length of the array, how many likes for that particular post/image.

So here is the logic that increments the like value, and this works, it will increment to infinity, which is not what i want. Im looking for is the reducer logic that will take care of the decrement value, just as the `POST_LIKE_SUCCESS` does

`console.log( newState.images.find(image => image.id === action.data).likes)`

data structure as followed

**Data structure.**

```
{
  "id": 154,
  "image_title": "iiisdd",
  "img_url": "https://res*******",
  "created_at": "2019-07-18T19:44:49.805Z",
  "updated_at": "2019-07-18T19:44:49.805Z",
  "user_id": 1,
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "googleId": null,
    "username": "E*******",
    "password": "$***********JwCO",
    "email": "e******",
    "created_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z"
  },
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 51,
      "comment_body": "owls life",
      "created_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:51.484Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:51.484Z",
      "user_id": 8,
      "image_id": 154,
      "user": {
        "id": 8,
        "googleId": null,
        "username": "guest",
        "password": "$************",
        "email": "***********l.com",
        "created_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:34.315Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:34.315Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 52,
      "comment_body": "dadad",
      "created_at": "2019-07-19T20:16:40.103Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-19T20:16:40.103Z",
      "user_id": 1,
      "image_id": 154,
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "googleId": null,
        "username": "**********",
        "password": "$*********O",
        "email": "e*******m",
        "created_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 53,
      "comment_body": "test",
      "created_at": "2019-07-21T22:12:44.729Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-21T22:12:44.729Z",
      "user_id": 1,
      "image_id": 154,
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "googleId": null,
        "username": "E******d",
        "password": "$********4WjO",
        "email": "********",
        "created_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "likes": [
    {
      "id": 24,
      "user_id": 2,
      "image_id": 154,
      "created_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z",
      "deleted_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z",
      "restored_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 77,
      "user_id": 1,
      "image_id": 154,
      "created_at": "2019-07-23T02:55:31.051Z",
      "deleted_at": "2019-07-23T02:55:31.051Z",
      "restored_at": "2019-07-23T02:55:31.051Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-23T02:55:31.051Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to delete the like, similar to redux boilerplate counter like this.

```
state - 1
```

**reducer**

```
import {
  UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
  POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS,
  DELETE_IMAGE_FAILURE,
  FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS,
  DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
  POST_COMMENT,
  POST_LIKE,
  POST_LIKE_SUCCESS,
  POST_LIKE_FAILURE,
  DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  images: [],
  likedByuser: false,
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        images: action.images,
      };
    .....
    case DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
      // console.log(action)
      return {
        ...state,
        images: state.images.filter(img => img.id !== action.data),
      };
    case DELETE_IMAGE_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error,
      };
    case POST_LIKE_SUCCESS:
      console.log(action.data);
      const newState = { ...state }; // here I am trying to shallow  copy the existing state;
      const existingLikesOfPost = newState.images.find(image => image.id === action.data).likes;
      console.log(existingLikesOfPost)
      newState.images.find(image => image.id === action.data).likes = [...existingLikesOfPost, action.newLikeObject]; // using this approach I got some code duplication so I suggested the first approach of using **push** method of array.


      // console.log(newState)
      return newState;
    case DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
      console.log(action.data)
      // working on logic that will decrement
      return{
        ...state - 1
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

console.log(action.data)

```
{
  "type": "POST_LIKE",
  "data": {
    "id": 154,
  }
}
```

**express backend logic**

```
router.post('/like/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  if (id !== null || 'undefined') {
    Image.forge({ id })
      .fetch({ withRelated: ['user', 'comments', 'likes'] })
      .then((likes) => {
        const like = likes.toJSON();
        // console.log(like.likes);
        const existingUserlikes = like.likes.map(user => user.user_id);
        // checking to see if a user already liked his own post
        // if existing user does not have user id, user can like post,
        // else if user already like this post wont be able to.

        const newLike = new Likes({
          image_id: id,
          user_id: req.user.id
        });
        if (existingUserlikes.includes(req.user.id)) {
        // !newLike do not create a new row of likes if like from this user already exists
          if (!newLike) {
            Likes.forge().where({ user_id: req.user.id, image_id: id }).destroy();
          }
          return Likes.forge().where({user_id: req.user.id, image_id: id }).fetch()
              .then((like) => like.destroy()
              .then( () => res.json({ error: true, data: { message: 'like deleted' } })));
        }
        newLike.save().then(like => res.status(200).json({ status: 'You liked this post', like: newLike }));
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: I dont quite get the question. Whats the data structure for? Whats the shape of images and likes? How do you want to delete the likes?

Comment: ill post full data structure. I want to delete the likes similar to. `state - 1`

Comment: similar to redux boilerplate reducer count increment or decrement. I want the same functionalities on the front end.

Comment: what about filtering array and returning elements that are not equal to the user id?

Comment: how would you go about writing the logic. Given the logic the POST_LIKE_SUCCESS case  ? Could you provide an answer

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you are complicating things. Personally, I wouldn't structure my data like that. Deeply nested objects should be avoided. You can instead have several objects that are linked to each other. Also, I would have the post ids as object keys, so when I want to update a specific post, I just need to

```
return {
  ...state,
  [action.id]: {
    ...state[action.id],
    ...action.newData,
  }
}
```

In your case, I would just filter out the user id that disliked the post:

```
...
case DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
  const newState = { ...state };
  const predicate = ({ id }) => id === action.data;
  const existingLikes = newState.images.find(predicate).likes;
  // You would have to pass userId as an action payload as I'm assuming you are deleting 
  // the likes based on the userId.
  const newLikes = existingLikes.filter(({ user_id }) => user_id !== action.userId);  
  newState.images.find(predicate).likes = newLikes;
```

Comment: its the post id Brian, not the user id. action.data is === to the post id. Will try this out, and let you know how it went, thanks for this :)

Comment: @BARNOWL isn't that the image id used in `predicate`?

Comment: ill console.log(action.data) for a better insight. one sec.

Comment: ok i updated the code. going to give this a shot. id is the image_id

Comment: @BARNOWL So u want to remove a like based on the userId? Whats the criteria for removing a like?

Comment: remove the like based on the imageId. not the user id. Pretty much im trying to toggle like and dislike. So in backend perspective add like, and it removes like from table. Ill show express back end Brian.

Comment: But how would you know what like to delete? @BARNOWL

Comment: @BARNOWL If you delete likes based on image id, you can might as well empty the likes array. What's the point?

Comment: whats a better way to toggle between like and unlike. How would you do this ? For example a facebook like.  Or this heroku example https://radiant-temple-15197.herokuapp.com

Comment: @BARNOWL When u click the like button, you always pass in the userId. If the like made by the user has existed, you remove it otherwise you add it

Comment: would i need to refactor the backend logic call  ?

Comment: @BARNOWL, sorry but you would need to open a new question for that. This is going out of the scope

Comment: where would i go to learn more about avoiding nested objects in reducers ? Doing it the way you told me ?

Comment: @BARNOWL There's no such thing to learn. It depends on how you use the data. In this case, you have to update the post objects quite often based on their ids. Isn't it better just to use them as object keys instead of dumping everything in an array?

Comment: Sorry for not knowing how to manipulate object keys, i feel stupid now.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to use an [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper). This enables you to update an object immutable without worrying about the whole object.
You could update it like this:

`return update(state, {
        likes: {$remove: [action.id]}
});`

If you change your like object later on, you don't have to change this part of the code, because it will only update the mentioned data.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i made another post about refactoring my reducer code. Let me know your thoughts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171473/is-their-a-better-way-to-restructure-a-nested-object-reducer