# better way to return states within nested objects in a reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm retrieving data from a backend, the data structure is like this.

Data Strucuture

```
{
  "id": 154,
  "image_title": "iiisdd",
  "img_url": "*********",
  "created_at": "2019-07-18T19:44:49.805Z",
  "updated_at": "2019-07-18T19:44:49.805Z",
  "user_id": 1,
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "googleId": null,
    "username": "*******,
    "password": "$********",
    "email": "e*******",
    "created_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z"
  },
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 51,
      "comment_body": "owls life",
      "created_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:51.484Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:51.484Z",
      "user_id": 8,
      "image_id": 154,
      "user": {
        "id": 8,
        "googleId": null,
        "username": "guest",
        "password": "********u",
        "email": "*******m",
        "created_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:34.315Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-07-18T20:04:34.315Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 52,
      "comment_body": "dadad",
      "created_at": "2019-07-19T20:16:40.103Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-19T20:16:40.103Z",
      "user_id": 1,
      "image_id": 154,
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "googleId": null,
        "username": "*******",
        "password": "*********",
        "email": "el***********",
        "created_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 53,
      "comment_body": "test",
      "created_at": "2019-07-21T22:12:44.729Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-21T22:12:44.729Z",
      "user_id": 1,
      "image_id": 154,
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "googleId": null,
        "username": "********",
        "password": "*********",
        "email": "el********",
        "created_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "likes": [
    {
      "id": 24,
      "user_id": 2,
      "image_id": 154,
      "created_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z",
      "deleted_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z",
      "restored_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-22T19:26:27.034Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 141,
      "user_id": 1,
      "image_id": 154,
      "created_at": "2019-07-23T19:57:08.178Z",
      "deleted_at": "2019-07-23T19:57:08.178Z",
      "restored_at": "2019-07-23T19:57:08.178Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-23T19:57:08.178Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't think im passing the data in reducer quite efficiently. What is a better way to refactor this code so that i can easily map the data on the component/ui.

Without having to do `{this.props.image.images.comments}` or `{this.props.images.likes}` etc.

I want to implement this reducer example

https://github.com/hibiken/hackafy/blob/master/src/reducers/posts.js

but unsure if i really need too.

**Reducer**

```
import {
  UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
  POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS,
  DELETE_IMAGE_FAILURE,
  FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS,
  DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
  POST_COMMENT,
  POST_LIKE,
  POST_LIKE_SUCCESS,
  POST_LIKE_FAILURE,
  DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS,
} from '../actions/types';
const initialState = {
  images: [],
  likedByuser: false,
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        images: action.images,
      };
    case UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
      const newImage = action.data;
      return {
        images: [
          {
            id: newImage[0].id,
            user: {
              username: newImage[0].user.username,
            },
            comments: {
              comment_body: newImage[0].comments.comment_body,
            },
            image_title: newImage[0].image_title,
            img_url: newImage[0].img_url,
          },
          ...state.images, // pass the previous images,
        ],
      };
    case DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
      // console.log(action)
      return {
        ...state,
        images: state.images.filter(img => img.id !== action.data),
      };
    case DELETE_IMAGE_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error,
      };
    case POST_LIKE:
      console.log(action);
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case POST_LIKE_SUCCESS:
      console.log(action.data);
      const newState = { ...state }; // here I am trying to shallow  copy the existing state;
      const existingLikesOfPost = newState.images.find(image => image.id === action.data).likes;
      console.log(existingLikesOfPost)
      newState.images.find(image => image.id === action.data).likes = [...existingLikesOfPost, action.newLikeObject]; // using this approach I got some code duplication so I suggested the first approach of using **push** method of array.
      return newState;
    case DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
      // ....
    case POST_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
      //  adds a comment to a post without having to re render.
      // console.log(action.data.commentBody);
      return {
        ...state,
        images: state.images.map((image) => {
          // appends new comment withing images redux state. only if image.id === action.id
          if (image.id === action.id) {
            return {
              ...image,
              comments: [
                ...image.comments,
                {
                  comment_body: action.data[0].comment_body,
                  user: {
                    username: action.data[0].user.username,
                  },
                },
              ],
            };
          }
          return image;
        }),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normalize your state as explained in the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape).
The key points:

1. You should keep your store as flat as possible
2. Try to reduce duplicate information => only set ids references instead of actual data
3. don't use arrays to store your data, because you will have to use find or filter a lot, instead use a map/object with the key as the access point to the actual object like this:

   `comments: {comment_id1: {title: 'title', author:'author_id'}}`

to get all comments, add a allComments array with only the ids like this

```
allComments: ['comment_id1']
```

You should use a new reducer for each of these subsets of data.
If you have more questions, let me know or read the docs.

Comment: similar to the way this is setup https://github.com/hibiken/hackafy/blob/master/src/reducers/posts.js right ?

Comment: yes, if your app grows, you will find it easier to keep everything in sync and with only one source of truth. This will dramatically reduce your complexity of your reducer which is more valuable than just copying the data from the backend into the state and deal with the nested updates within the reducer itself.